# What is the configuration for integrating ReactJS to existing Android App?

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, react-native

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.net.ConnectivityManagerCompat.()' is inaccessible to class 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' (declaration of 'com.facebook.react.modules.netinfo.NetInfoModule' appears in /data/app/package.name-2/base.apk)

I'm getting this after JS bundle load.

gradle:

compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.2'

package.json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.28.0"
  }

I have also tried with various reactJS and appcompat version but no luck.